# JQuery: How to find dropdown in same table row when another dropdown value will be changed in that row

Tags: jquery

i am working with cascade dropdown and i know how to populate 2nd dropdown on the change of 1st dropdown in a page.

here is a sample code to handle cascade dropdown by jquery in a page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event     
        $("#SelectedStateID").change(function () {   
            $("#SelectedCountryID").empty();   
            $.ajax({   
                type: 'POST',   
               url: '@Url.Action("GetCountrys")', // we are calling json method     
                dataType: 'json',   
                data: { id: $("#SelectedStateID").val() },   
                success: function (states) {   
                    // states contains the JSON formatted list     
                    // of Countrys passed from the controller     

                   $("#SelectedCountryID").append('<option value="' + "0" + '">' + "Select Country" + '</option>');   
                    debugger;   
                    $.each(states, function (i, state) {   
                        $("#SelectedCountryID").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' + state.Text + '</option>');   
                       // here we are adding option for Countrys     
                    });   
                },   
                error: function (ex) {   
                    alert('Failed to retrieve Country.' + ex);   
                }   
            });   
            return false;   
       })   
    });
```

but my problem is suppose when there is two dropdown in two column of html table of every row then when user select one dropdown then how to find 2nd dropdown in another column of same row to populate it. please help me with code sample if possible. thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using a clientside binding framework/library like knockout.js or angular js to perform this task, it would be very well suited to doing something like this.

Comment: Add a css class to each dropdown. After that bind the change event as per `class`. Above you have bind as per `id`, change that use class selector. And when your change event trigger add the dropdown option in side that row dropdown only. You can do that by parent `tr` and then find class of the dropdown you want to change.

Comment: It would be more better if you Upload any image or explain properly to get a more clear answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If the first is select is always changing the first select of another column, and the second is always changing the second of another, you could loop through the table row, like so:

```
 $("tr.SelectRow").each(function(index) {
    var thisRow = $(this);
    thisRow.find('select.SelectedState').change(function () { 
        var countrySelect = thisRow.find('select.SelectedCountry');  
        countrySelect.empty();
```

Comment: sorry not clear your code. suppose state dropdown is in first column of every row of html table and city dropdown is in 2nd column of every row of html table. suppose there is 10 records or 10 rows in html table. if user select state from state dropdown from 3rd row of table then i need to find out city dropdown in same row and populate it. what your code is doing not clear.

Comment: i guess your code is iterating in dropdown but i am not after that.

Comment: what is `SelectRow` and `SelectedState` please work with id like ddlState and ddlCity.

Comment: where you add change evenet. how u r tracking dropdown data change by user?

Comment: @Thomas It won't work with ID's because they must be unique. I've given you a simple example of how you could change your code to be dynamic like you are wanting it to be. If you understood how the code in your example works, you _should_ be able to work it out. I'm not going to spoon feed you by writing out the whole working solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $('table select').change(function(){        //'select' can be customize by giving class selector to all table element
      $(this).closest('tr').find('select').each(function(){
         //$(this)   //select box of same row
         console.log($(this).find(":selected").text());
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*****//Your html table*****

```
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="firstSelectBox">
         <option value="1" selected>1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td>
      <select class="secondSelectBox">
      </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <select class="firstSelectBox">
         <option value="3" selected>3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td>
      <select class="secondSelectBox">
         <option></option>
      </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
```

*****//sample php page named getOption.php for ajax response*****

```
<?php 
    echo "<option id='1'>1</option><option id='2'>2</option>";
?>
```

***//your jquery code***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.firstSelectBox").each(function(event){
        $(this).on("change",function(event){
            var id = $(this).val();
            var toBePopulated = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").children("td").children("select.secondSelectBox");
            toBePopulated.empty();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getOption.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {id:id},
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                toBePopulated.append(data);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("complete");
            });
        })
    })
```